# pandas apply() results in UnboundLocalError

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply

I have a dataframe (df_cluster) with 2 columns [Customer Id, Cluster]. There are around 13 clusters and I am trying to assign a name to each cluster using apply() in python. I have used the same function in the past and it worked fine, but now I am getting "UnboundLocalError" error.

Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong. My understanding of apply() is that it passes the function across the axis (in this case function cluster_name would be passed for each row)

Here's the code

```
def cluster_name(df):
    if df['cluster'] == 1:
        value = 'A'
    elif df['cluster'] == 2:
        value = 'B'    
    elif df['cluster'] == 3:
        value = 'C'
    elif df['cluster'] == 4:
        value = 'D'
    elif df['cluster'] == 5:
        value = 'E'
    elif df['cluster'] == 6:
        value = 'F'
    elif df['cluster'] == 7:
        value = 'G'
    return value

df_cluster['cluster_name'] = df_cluster.apply(cluster_name, axis = 1)
```

Error

```
UnboundLocalError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-b64f3fdc1260> in <module>
     16     return value
     17 
---> 18 df_cluster['cluster_name'] = df_cluster.apply(cluster_name, axis = 1)
     19 df_cluster['cluster_name'].value_counts()

/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, broadcast, raw, reduce, result_type, args, **kwds)
   6926             kwds=kwds,
   6927         )
-> 6928         return op.get_result()
   6929 
   6930     def applymap(self, func):

/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in get_result(self)
    184             return self.apply_raw()
    185 
--> 186         return self.apply_standard()
    187 
    188     def apply_empty_result(self):

/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply_standard(self)
    290 
    291         # compute the result using the series generator
--> 292         self.apply_series_generator()
    293 
    294         # wrap results

/opt/cloudera/parcels/Anaconda/envs/py36/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in apply_series_generator(self)
    319             try:
    320                 for i, v in enumerate(series_gen):
--> 321                     results[i] = self.f(v)
    322                     keys.append(v.name)
    323             except Exception as e:

<ipython-input-16-b64f3fdc1260> in cluster_name(df)
     14     elif df['cluster'] == 7:
     15         value = 'G'
---> 16     return value
     17 
     18 df_cluster['cluster_name'] = df_cluster.apply(cluster_name, axis = 1)

UnboundLocalError: ("local variable 'value' referenced before assignment", 'occurred at index 0')
'''
```

Comment: Seems like one of the values in your column is not present in your function. What is the expected behavior if `df['cluster'] > 7`? Then `value` never gets assigned but you try to return it anyway. Try assigning something to `value` initially, or using a catch-all `else:` at the end before you return

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your question has been answered in the comments, so I'm going to propose a more pandas oriented method to solving your issue. Using `apply(axis=1)` with a DataFrame is horribly slow and almost never necessary (same with iterating over the rows in a dataframe), so a better method would be to use a vectorized approach. The simplest way to do this is to define your cluster -> cluster_name mappings in a dictionary, and use the `map` method:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {"cluster": [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]}
)

# repeat this dataframe 10000 times
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000)
```

apply method:

```
def mapping_func(row):
    if row['cluster'] == 1:
        value = 'A'
    elif row['cluster'] == 2:
        value = 'B'    
    elif row['cluster'] == 3:
        value = 'C'
    elif row['cluster'] == 4:
        value = 'D'
    elif row['cluster'] == 5:
        value = 'E'
    elif row['cluster'] == 6:
        value = 'F'
    elif row['cluster'] == 7:
        value = 'G'
    else:
        # This is a "catch-all" in case none of the values in the column are 1-7
        value = "Z"
        
    return value

%timeit df.apply(mapping_func, axis=1)
# 1.32 s ± 91.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

`.map` approach

```
mapping_dict = {
    1: "A",
    2: "B",
    3: "C",
    4: "D",
    5: "E",
    6: "F",
    7: "G"
}

# the `fillna` is our "catch-all" statement.
#  essentially if `map` encounters a value not in the dictionary
#  it will place a NaN there. So I fill those NaNs with "Z" to
#  be consistent with the above example
%timeit df["cluster"].map(mapping_dict).fillna("Z")
# 4.87 ms ± 195 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

We can see that the `map` with dictionary approach is vastly faster than the `apply` while also avoiding a long chain of `if/elif` statements.

Answer (score 0):

There is an `else` missing in your function:

```
def cluster_name(df):
    if df['cluster'] == 1:
        value = 'A'
    elif df['cluster'] == 2:
        value = 'B'    
    elif df['cluster'] == 3:
        value = 'C'
    elif df['cluster'] == 4:
        value = 'D'
    elif df['cluster'] == 5:
        value = 'E'
    elif df['cluster'] == 6:
        value = 'F'
    elif df['cluster'] == 7:
        value = 'G'
    else:
        value = ...
    return value
```

Otherwise `value` will not be set if `df['cluster']` is not among the values {1, 2, ..., 7}, and that gives the exception.

Answer (score 0):

- Manually creating `if-else` functions, is overrated, and a condition may be missed.
- Since you're assigning letters as the `'cluster_name'`, use [`string.ascii_uppercase`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#string.ascii_uppercase) to get a `list` of all the letters, and [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#zip) them to the unique values in `'cluster'`

  - Create a `dict` from the zipped values and [`.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) to create the `'cluster_name'` column.
- This implementation uses the unique values in the column to create the map, so there won't be an issue with `"local variable 'value' referenced before assignment"`.

  - In the case of your error, it is caused because `return value` executes when there is a value in the column that is not in your `if-else` conditions, which means `value` is not assigned in the function.

```py
import pandas as pd
import string

# test dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame({'cluster': range(1, 11)})

# unique values from the cluster column
clusters = sorted(df.cluster.unique()) 

# create a dict to map
cluster_map = dict(zip(clusters, string.ascii_uppercase))

# create the cluster_name column
df['cluster_name'] = df.cluster.map(cluster_map)

# df
   cluster cluster_name
0        1            A
1        2            B
2        3            C
3        4            D
4        5            E
5        6            F
6        7            G
7        8            H
8        9            I
9       10            J
```